# Registering callbacks for FunctionalTestComponents

Tags: mule

I'm trying to register a callback for a given Functional Test Component defined in the xml as a singleton-object.  I'm working directly from the documentation on Mule's site, but looking at the below, I don't see how the call to `getFunctionalTestCOmponent("TestComponentService").setEventCallback(callback);` is able to find the singleton, since the name TestComponentService is not associated with the component.  I've attempted this myself with no luck.  I've also tried adding doc:name="TestComponentService" to the component, but still no luck.  Any idea how to make this example below functional?

```
public void testEventCallback() throws Exception 
{
    EventCallback callback = new EventCallback()
    {
        public void eventReceived(MuleEventContext context, Object component) 
            throws Exception
        {
            System.out.println("Thanks for calling me back");
        }
    };

    getFunctionalTestComponent("TestComponentService").setEventCallback(callback);

    MuleClient client = new MuleClient();

    client.send("vm://test", new DefaultMuleMessage("foo"));
 }


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mule xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:vm="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm"
    xmlns:test="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/test"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
    http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
    http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm/current/mule-vm.xsd
    http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/test http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/test/current/mule-test.xsd">

<flow name="TestComponentFlow">
    <inbound-endpoint address="vm://test" exchange-pattern="request-response" />  
    <component>
        <singleton-object class="org.mule.tck.functional.FunctionalTestComponent"/>
    </component>
</flow>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be 'TestComponentFlow' it looks it up by flow name.

So use:

```
getFunctionalTestComponent("TestComponentFlow").setEventCallback(callback);
```

Comment: Ah.  Strange.  So, the official documentation isn't right or clear...  Bummer.  Thanks!